# Is is possible to re-purchase an app for which I requested a refund?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

Yes, it sounds strange. I purchased an app that didn't initially work and I requested a refund which was promptly processed by Apple. Then I couldn't find a better app for my needs and figured out some workarounds for the initial app. Now I still have the app installed on my phone and the honest thing to do is repurchase it. How can I do that?

Comment: What happens when you try to purchase it through the App Store normally?

Comment: The AppStore gets confused. It says that the app was purchased through a different account (not true) and suggests to log through the other account (which I don't have).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Once an app is refunded, you cannot re-purchase it, for all eternity. I've spent about 2h with various levels of Apple support without success.

Also, it's worth mentioning that you cannot get updates for a refunded app (makes sense).